# Android видео камера

Tags: android, видео, камера

Подскажите, как запустить со своего приложения, камеру телефона?
И приложите пожалуйста ссылки на работу с камерой.

Comment: Зачем минусовать, напишите лучше, что по вышему мнению не так!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ща в андроид есть двa API для камеры - Camera и Camera2. Так как Camera считается устаревшей, то использовать лучше Camera2. Использование его, по сравнению с первым достаточно зубодробительное, по этому рекомендую воспользоваться готовой библиотекой. Например этой https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6100, во всяком случае ею я пользовался.. Инструкция по применению вполне подробная.